# Problem while reading contacts with ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android

I need to search a particular name from ma contacts... for that i gave the selection criteria like this

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '"+constraint+"%'"
```

But for apostrophe(')... means ...when i gave apostrophe as **constraint** an (**SQL error** )exception is thrown.. for all other special characters , the search is working..

How can we handle constraint **apostrophe(')...** in search criteria.. boz we can have contact names having **apostrophe** in it **(Eg: Jennifer'lo'pe_z)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***How do I use a string literal that contains an embedded single-quote (') character?***

*The SQL standard specifies that single-quotes in strings are escaped by putting two single quotes in a row. SQL works like the Pascal programming language in the regard. SQLite follows this standard.*

Example:

```
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES('5 O''clock');
```

SO, simply for your solution, use '' at the place of '. like

```
if(constraint.contains("'")) 
            constraint = constraint.replace("'", "''");
```

And then execute your query. This must help you.

Happy coding :)